# How to pull data from API in background thread based on time interval in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an **Android Application**. The requirement is to *pull some data(tables) from* **API** and save it in **sqlite** database based on **time interval**. There will be a timer running in background and that will hit API to pull data in a particular interval and insert/update it to sqlite. It will be appreciable if I get a piece of complete code.

I found a solution but my confusion is if I call this function in One Activity(Launcher Activity) and going to another activity will keep this action working in background or it will be destroyed.

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                        performBackgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 50000); //execute in every 50000 ms
}
```

Here's a link : [check and pull data from server continuously in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498403/check-and-pull-data-from-server-continuously-in-android-application)

Comment: put that code inside a Service instead of an Activity. Service will keep running even if the activity gets destroyed.

Comment: use runnable , it will not stop as going to another activity or fragment  rurnable use it's own thread that is background thread.

Comment: Getting error on declaring : final Handler handler = new Handler(); @Darish